# Can a html object pass itself as an argument to a JS function

Tags: html, arguments

Let's say I have a HTML code looking like this:

```
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe()">1</div>
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe()">2</div>
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe()">3</div>
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe()">4</div>
```

I would like my `clickMe` function to output something like this:
`You clicked the button No. 3`

In other words, I need each button to pass "itself" as an argument to the function... Is it possible ?
Like `<div class="button" onclick="clickMe(self)">2</div>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use pass the `this` keyword to your `clickMe` method, which will refer to the element clicked. You can then use `.textContent` to retrieve the number from the clicked `div`

```js
function clickMe(elem) {
  console.log("You have clicked " +elem.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe(this)">1</div>
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe(this)">2</div>
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe(this)">3</div>
<div class="button" onclick="clickMe(this)">4</div>
```

Alternatively, you can instead use the `click` event listener, which will prevent you from repeating the same function call on each element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("You have clicked " +this.textContent);
  });  
});
```

```html
<div class="button">1</div>
<div class="button">2</div>
<div class="button">3</div>
<div class="button">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `id` element and then you can pass `this.id`.

```js
function clickMe(val) 
  { alert("You clicked the button No. "+val); }
```

```html
<div class="button" id = "1" onclick="clickMe(this.id)">1</div>
<div class="button" id = "2" onclick="clickMe(this.id)">2</div>
<div class="button" id = "3" onclick="clickMe(this.id)">3</div>
<div class="button" id = "4" onclick="clickMe(this.id)">4</div>
```